# Current date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a calendar that has a wrong behaviour.
As soon as someone opens it there's a wrong date selected. 
I'd like it to show the current date when opened. 
This is what happens now: 
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input id="dataClass" type="text" name="input"
        placeholder="gg-mm-aaaa"
        tooltip="Inserire una data nel formato gg-mm-aaaa"
        tooltip-placement="bottom" class="form-control input-sm"
        custom-datepicker-pattern="{{customDatePattern}}"
        datepicker-popup="{{formatoDataDatePicker}}"
        show-button-bar="false" ng-model="systemDate"
        is-open="status.opened" min-date="'01-01-1900'" max-date="maxDate"
        datepicker-options="dateOptions"
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
        close-text="Chiudi" current-text="Oggi" /> 
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        ng-click="open($event)" tooltip="Cambia data timbro"
        tooltip-placement="right">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.today = new Date();
$scope.dt = $filter('date')($scope.today , 'yyyy-MM-dd');
$scope.systemDate = $filter('date')($scope.dt , 'dd-MM-yyyy'); 
$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
};

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.toggleMax = function() {
    $scope.maxDate = $scope.maxDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMax();

$scope.maxDate = $filter('date')($scope.today , 'yyyy-MM-dd');

$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.status.opened = true;
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem.

Comment: Could you `console.log($scope.maxDate)`? Does the `datepicker-options="dateOptions"` work? Shouldn't it be `datepicker-options="{{dateOptions}}"`

Answer (score 1):

In your directive's config you've set:

```
 ng-model="systemDate"
```

In your code you set for this var:
$scope.systemDate = $filter('date')($scope.dt , 'dd-MM-yyyy');

You have to change from:

```
$scope.systemDate = $filter('date')($scope.dt , 'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

to

```
$scope.systemDate = $scope.today();
```

Comment: this solves the problem but only partially. I want the date in the format dd-MM-yyyy. Could you please update your answer so I can accept it? :)